# Python: Create a dictionary with empty list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want a list like this
`{'A': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'B': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],..., 'Z': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}`

So a list in length 5 from A to Z.

I try this but I think the code can be more compact:

`mydict = {'A': [0] * 5, 'B': [0] * 5,..., 'Z': [0] * 5}`

how can i get the code more compact?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you clarify? Your title says you want an empty list, your question says you want a list of letters, your code says your want a dict from letters to non-empty lists.

Answer (score 7):

Use the string package.

```
import string
mydict = { x : [0]*5 for x in string.ascii_uppercase}
```

Answer (score 1):

without importing any package/module you could do:

```
mydict = {chr(i):[0]*5 for i in range(65, 65 + 26)} # 65 is the ascii for A while 91 is for Z
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import string 
# initializing empty list  
test_list = [] 
test_list = list(string.ascii_lowercase) 
 mydict = { x : [0]*5 for x in test_list}
print(mydict)
```